# Как должен выглядеть и работать правильный Router в PHP MVC приложении?

Tags: php, ооп, mvc, фреймворк

### Предисловие

Всем доброго времени суток!
Так вышло, что я решил перейти с front-end на back-end.
Я очень дотошный кодер. Поэтому я всегда стараюсь вникнуть в суть и понять как все устроено, а затем уже изучать инструменты, которые облегчают работу.

Очень прошу вас не давать ответы типа: "Не делай велосипед! Учи фреймворк!".

Я хочу сделать действительно качественный и полнофункциональный PHP фреймворк.
Все, что есть в интернете — Bad Practice. Или решения из ряда **"Сейчас мы сделаем что-то, что нельзя будет использовать без серьезнейшей доработки или что вообще является лишь образным примером"**.
Все платный курсы, которые я нашел, дают лишь базовое понимание. Они учат, как сделать что-то простое, чему нельзя найти применение.
А разбирать код других фреймворков мне пока немного тяжело.

### Суть

Саму концепцию я понимаю. Я знаком с ООП и раньше занимался разработкой iOS приложений.
Самой большой проблемой для меня является динамический роутинг, диспетчер.
В интернете я нашел лишь простецкую реализацию этих элементов.

Например, роутер.
В данный момент, я представляю динамический роутинг так:

- разбиваем URL на части при помощи слешей и заносим это в массив;
- нулевой элемент массива — это контроллер, второй — это экшн,
  остальные — это параметры;
- В том случае, если экшена нет – запускается дефолтный метод
  (например, когда адрес типа example.com/about);
- вызываем контроллер.

Также, в одной статье прочитал, что очень хорошо иметь белый список из контроллеров для предотвращения некоторого вида атак.

В общем, у меня не хватает знаний для полноты картины, которые я очень хочу получить. Надеюсь, что здесь мне смогут помочь :)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ba3M3_Myrqg&list=PLSdH7dYnlGYgQ6ElbHRpG2zRXbkgkO3zQ

Comment: То что вы описали - это один из вариантов. Но он не будет поддерживать или будет плохо поддерживать SEO url. Есть ещё часто используемый вариант с параметром (route, dispatch и т.д.).

Comment: "Я хочу сделать действительно качественный и полнофункциональный PHP фреймворк" https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/images/6/60/standards.png

Comment: https://elisdn.ru/blog/124/psr7-console-db-assets начните с 1 урока и до 7. Всё по полочкам разложено. Объяснено что к чему. Количество велосипедов и костылей стремится к 0. Смотреть видео в первом комментарии не советую